# Defining a union type based on object's property in array functionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have a bunch of arrays with enums and their human readable counterparts.

I was hoping to be able to build a enum union type for each possible variation dynamically as some of the arrays are rather long.

```
interface EnumType { enumValue: string, value: string }
export type enumArrayType = Array<EnumType> 

export const cpuSocket: enumArrayType = [
  { enumValue: 'LGA1150', value: 'LGA 1150' },
  { enumValue: 'LGA1151', value: 'LGA 1151' }
]

export const cpuBrand: enumArrayType = [
  { enumValue: 'INTEL', value: 'Intel' },
  { enumValue: 'AMD', value: 'Amd' }
]

type CpuBrandEnumTypes = 'INTEL' | 'AMD'

type cpuType = {
  brand: CpuBrandEnumTypes
}
const cpu: cpuType = {}
cpu.brand: CpuBrandEnumTypes = INTEL // WORKS!
cpu.brand: CpuBrandEnumTypes = intel // ERROR!
cpu.brand: CpuBrandEnumTypes = amd // ERROR!
cpu.brand: CpuBrandEnumTypes = AMD // WORKS!
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should be able to do so, the only thing missing in your code is defining your `enumArrayType` like this: `interface enumArrayType {enumValue: CpuManufactuersEnumTypes; value: string;}`.

Comment: I've clarified the example @GalTalmor

Comment: btw i'm trying to set the CpuBrandEnumTypes dynamically from the values of enumValue

Comment: If you're setting it from the cpuBrand, `enumValue: string` should be `enumValue: CpuBrandEnumTypes ` right?

Comment: Added cpu sockets to show the enumArrayType should be shared.

But throughout my app i'd like to just have a cpu brand enum type and ensure it's one of those values